# Use check box selected elements to filter report

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex-5

I have an issue with making a correct report for my application. The report is supposed to return free rooms for a set of parameters (including a list of equipements). However, I cannot include the equipements search in my interractive report.

Here is the SQL request I've got:

```
SELECT s.code || ' ' || s.nom as Salle, s.capacite, LISTAGG(eq.libelle, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY eq.code) as Equipements, b.libelle as Batiment, s.numero
FROM SALLES s
INNER JOIN batiments b ON
b.numero = s.bat_numero
INNER JOIN sal_gpe sg ON
s.numero = sg.sal_numero
INNER JOIN groupespersonnes gp ON
gp.numero = sg.gpe_numero
LEFT JOIN equ_sal e ON
e.sal_numero = s.numero
LEFT JOIN equipements eq ON 
eq.numero = e.equ_numero

-- On vérifie les salles visibles pour le groupe de personne affecté à l'utilisateur connecté. 
WHERE gp.code = (SELECT code FROM groupespersonnes INNER JOIN personnes p ON p.gpe_numero = groupespersonnes.numero WHERE UPPER(:APP_USER) = UPPER(p.username))

AND :P30_PERIODE_DEBUT NOT IN (SELECT per_numero FROM enregistrements WHERE sal_numero = s.numero AND TO_CHAR(jour, 'DD.MM.RR') = :P30_DATE)
AND :P30_PERIODE_FIN NOT IN (SELECT per_numero FROM enregistrements WHERE sal_numero = s.numero AND TO_CHAR(jour, 'DD.MM.RR') = :P30_DATE)

AND e.equ_numero = regexp_substr(:P30_EQUIPEMENTS,'[^:]+')
GROUP BY s.capacite, s.nom, b.libelle, s.numero, s.code
```

I'm doing a LISTAGG on the equipements, so that I can show all the equipements for one room fit in one cell. Now :P30_EQUIPEMENT is actually a STRING. It takes the number of the equipements selected from the checkbox list (Dynamic LOV), and separates them with a ":". I've been trying many solutions but nothing worked. I'm now diving in the PL/SQL option.

If you have a idea of an easier way, I'd gladly take it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what :P30_EQUIPMENTS contains, then you should:

```
SQL> with test (p30_equipments) as
  2    (select 'tv:balcony:shower' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(p30_equipments, '[^:]+', 1, level) equipment
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(p30_equipments, ':') + 1;

EQUIPMENT
-----------------
tv
balcony
shower

SQL>
```

i.e. applied to your code:

```
and e.equ_numero in (select regexp_substr(:p30_equipments, '[^:]+', 1, level)
                     from dual
                     connect by level <= regexp_count(:p30_equipments, ':') + 1
                    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

P30_EQUIPEMENTS looks like "3:2:1", it could also be "1:3:2", depending on what order the user selected them. 

This code doesn't seem to solve my issue :(

Comment: 3:2:1 is equal to 1:3:2 or 2:1:3 or any other combination; subquery I wrote represents a "table" you're selecting from. What difference does it make? It just makes sure that E.EQU_NUMERO exists among those values. If that's not what you asked, huh, then I misunderstood the question.

Comment: It's working but as it was earlier. Which means, it finds the match for one equipement and only shows this one in the column. I need it to take all equipements into account and also be able to show them all in the LISTAGG.

Comment: If possible, create a SIMPLE test case - from a query you originally posted, remove all irrelevant information (joins with other tables) so that we'd see the INPUT and then show us what a desired OUTPUT looks like. As I said: I don't understand what you want. Or, wait for someone else, hopefully they'll be able to assist.

Comment: I'll make a test case from the application : 
Here are the form and the result table : 
https://imgur.com/ce0XOwK
Here are what the sessions variables look like : 
https://imgur.com/a/aYmGR3L

The resquest for the form bellow the first image is the same as the above request (except I've removed the "AND e.equ_numero = regexp_substr(:P30_EQUIPEMENTS,'[^:]+')" so that I can show you how I want them to be displayed.
Now the report has to filter the rooms with the equipements in the checkboxes...
I've been thinking of creating a function that build a request with a STRING..

Comment: I can't view images now (company policy), but this: `regexp_substr(:P30_EQUIPEMENTS,'[^:]+')` is wrong, it'll return only one value. I showed you what to do - you need a subquery (level, connect by, ... stuff).